# Rails URL doesn't show, only the view renders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have this route:

```
get 'events/new' => 'events#new'
```

and for this, an appropriate action and a template with `form_for` accepting an empty `@event` model object:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
```

Now, I also have this route:

```
post '/events' => 'events#hey'
```

and inside the `hey` action I don't do anything but let the view template take over which displays some static content.

Here's the problem: When I go to `site.com/events/new`, enter anything and click on the submit button, Rails redirects me to `site.com/events/`, displaying the content of the `hey.html.erb` view template!

Is this expected behavior? What I expected was to go to `site.com/events/hey`. Is there some implicit redirect of `form_for` does after the `POST` request?

Comment: can you please post all your event routes `rake routes | grep event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `post '/events' => 'events#hey'` brings you to '/events' where you just render the hey.html.erb template, but that doesn't change the url. What you want to do is this:

```
post '/events/hey' => 'events#hey'
```